# Setting up Sublime SFTP with EC2 Ubuntu 13

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sublimetext2, sftp

I'm on Windows 7, and I have my EC2 instance up and running. I have my key file, with permission 400. I can SSH into my EC2 and I can even sftp into it from command line (Cygwin) like so:

`sftp -i ~/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem ubuntu@54.***.***.149`

But Sublime's SFTP instantly throws a "Connection timeout" at me. I've tried both path types:

`/C/cygwin/home/Ehsan/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem`

`C:\\cygwin\\home\\Ehsan\\.ssh\\ekia_ec2.pem`

I've also tried using `"ssh_flags"` instead of `"ssh_key_file"`

`"sftp_flags": ["-i /C/cygwin/home/Ehsan/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem"]`

`"sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=/C/cygwin/home/Ehsan/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem"]`

Nothing works. Sublime 2, Windows 7 64bit, SFTP 1.11.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, I found it myself:

The SFTP plugin uses PSFTP.exe, and that doesn't work too well with .pem files. You'll need to convert it to a .ppk file and use that instead. I used PuTTy, but there are many ways you can convert it.

Comment: For anyone else reading, combine this answer with Rahul's! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to Ehsan Kia's comment, Please dont use these commands in Windows 7 to point to key file

```
"sftp_flags": ["-i /C/cygwin/home/Ehsan/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem"]

"sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=/C/cygwin/home/Ehsan/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem"]
```

instead use

```
"ssh_key_file": "C://...//yourkey.ppk"
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that was me after an hour of messing around with different variations of passing the key file to see if it'd work.

Answer (score -2):

The key file is in the format .pem and it won't work on the SFTP plugin. You can download FileZilla, which will convert it to a ppk file. And then, you'll be able to use the ppk file with the SFTP plugin on Sublime.